# Recharts customise YAxis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I want to customise the Y axis but have no idea if is it possible to do it with Recharts. I receive the following data:

```js
{ note: "C3", frequency: "1337", time: "13.37" }
```

I would like to see the `note`s like chart labels and use `frequency` for changing charts along the Y axis. Somehow I need to get the current frequency range eg: *from 1000 to 1500*, and to make breakpoints in the right places.

Can I realise this with Recharts or will it be easier to do it myself with canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Using Recharts, you can set your `frequency` prop as the YAxis range; just by setting the `dataKey` prop to `frequency`:

```js
<YAxis dataKey="frequency" />
```

This means that your YAxis range will be based on the `frequency` prop given on your data.